# Woran er nur wieder gedacht hatte

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Here is a sentence:

> Woran er nur wieder gedacht hatte!

I don't quite understand why this sentence follows the Nebensatz word order pattern. Is this a special type of a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This construct is called *Ausrufesatz*, see e. g. [here](https://www.studysmarter.de/schule/deutsch/grammatik/ausrufesatz/), at [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Satzart/Ausruf.xml?lang=de#id=3.1.4.b) or the grammar book of your choice. In such a sentence the verb may be located at the beginning or end of the sentence.

In your example the sentence (see subsection *Ausrufesetz mit Frage* in referenced page) expresses astonishment of the person itself, to which thoughts they deviated.